# Using redux-thunk and normalizr to create data objects from multiple API calls

Tags: reactjs, schema, redux, redux-thunk, normalizr

I'm using **redux-thunk** and **normalizr** to create a data schema. First, I grab a list of bills from a fetch call (not shown) and then for each item in the response, I make a separate API call (shown below) to get some terms related to that bill, using the bill's ID. That data is not provided in the outer fetch response.

I'm taking the normalized entities of terms for each bill, and before I dispatch to state, I'm replacing each entity object with a copy that includes a list of related bills.

*(Below code is working fine.)* My question is this: If I'm replacing each `termEntities[key]` with a copy of itself with the `relatedBills` property added on, does that count as mutating? Is it ok to mess around with the normalizr entity data before dispatching, or is this bad practice?

Thanks!

```js
export function fetchBillDetails(billId) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API}/${billId}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        const terms = json.terms;
        const normalizedTerms = normalize(terms, arrayOfTermSchema);
        const termEntities = normalizedTerms.entities.terms;

        for (const key in termEntities) {
          if (termEntities.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            termEntities[key] = Object.assign({}, termEntities[key], {
              relatedBills: billId
            })
          }
        }

        dispatch(receiveBillTerms(
          billId,
          normalizedTerms.entities,
          normalizedTerms.result
        ));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sure, you can do whatever you want on the data received from API. The only key point is that you never mutate data in the **state**.